# scapy srp() retrying send

Tags: scapy, single-responsibility-principle

I need your help.
I work with wi-fi monitor mode. I use scapy SENDP function and when I send 1 packet from PC1, i catch 5-7 packets on PC2, using SNIFF function. All these packets have besides 1 packet have FCfield = smth_i_set + retry.(smth_i_set is ,for example, 'wep' or 'MF' or 'MD')

And now my question: how to achieve sending only 1 packet, avoid all other packets with FCfield = smth_i_set + retry?
Maybe I should use srp function with RETRY = 0 ? 
Pls help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a wifi-card specific fix for this.

`sudo iw dev mon0 set noack_map 0x00ff`

This should work for Intel wifi cards that support it.